# Compare dates within the same column

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT title, DATE(end) AS Regresso FROM raddb.AgendaSaidas WHERE title = '763';
```

Returns the following data:

```
# title, Regresso
'763', '2023-01-11'
'763', '2023-01-08'
'763', '2023-01-07'
'763', '2023-01-01'
```

If you notice, there are two dates with a difference of 1 day, this one `2023-01-07` and this one `2023-01-08`.
I intend to compare these dates and in this situation only return the most recent date.
I want it to only return records where the date is different by at least 3 days.

I'm trying this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT title, DATE(end) AS Regresso
FROM raddb.AgendaSaidas AS d1, raddb.AgendaSaidas AS d2 
WHERE d1.title = '763' AND d2.title = '763' AND DATE(d1.end) >= (DATE(d2.end) + INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

I'll put the data I want it to return as:

```
# title, Regresso
'763', '2023-01-11'
'763', '2023-01-08'
'763', '2023-01-01'
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b92431/1)

Comment: Get LAG(DATE(end)) in CTE and return only those rows for which the difference is above 1.

Comment: not sure I understand if you also had 763/06 should that be discarded too?

Comment: @P. Salmão I intend to drop rows that are less than 3 days apart in the date for the same customer.

Comment: @Akina Can you put an example?

Comment: Provide sample data and desired output according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Comment: *I want it to only return records where the date is different by at least 3 days.* I.e. for the rows with dates '2023-01-07', '2023-01-09' and '2023-01-11' you'd receive only the last row?

Comment: @Akina In the question I showed the result I intended to return. In the initial data that I put in the question, only the line with this date '763', '2023-01-07' can leave. The other cases all have at least a difference of 3 days or more.

Comment: Please follow my request. Please answer my question, not your one.

Comment: @Akina Sorry, I didn't read the question well. In your question you can only return the last line, this '2023-01-11'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT title, 
           DATE(end) AS Regresso
    FROM raddb.AgendaSaidas 
    WHERE title = '763'
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT title, 
           Regresso, 
           DATEDIFF(LEAD(Regresso) OVER (ORDER BY Regresso), Regresso) delta
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT title, Regresso
FROM cte2
WHERE delta >= 3 OR delta IS NULL;
```

Comment: Can you help answer this question because it's a follow-up to this one? [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098215/dont-return-repeated-ids-and-give-priority-to-the-second-table)